# Range of magnification outside plane of focus in a microscope

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, microscopy

This should be a simple question, but somehow it's stumping me due to the way microscope objectives are, necessarily, built and classified (compared to, e.g., ideal thin lenses and photographic lenses):

What is the effective magnification of a (infinity-corrected compound) microscope *outside the focal plane*?

If a microscope objective has a nominal working distance of $x$ with a nominal magnification of $M$ at $x$, then is the effective (blurry, out-of-focus) magnification at a distance $x+\Delta x$ equal to $\frac{x + \Delta x}{x} M$? For example, given a 40x objective with a w.d. of 0.2 mm, is a 1 µm circle at 0.22 mm going to appear as large as a 1.1 µm circle at 0.2 mm; or, equivalently, as a 1 µm circle at 44x?

Obviously the resolution is going to be poorer the farther one goes from the focal plane, but I'm purely interested in determining the effective magnifications. This is relevant because I'm performing blob tracking on objects that can appear outside of the focal plane, and it seems that differences in magnification are making them appear larger or smaller than they are, but somehow I haven't found any references on this.

Comment: Have you performed an experiment on a stationary image of known size centered in your viewing field when moved above and below the focus plane?

Comment: I also had that idea today—but, unfortunately, I no longer have access to the microscope itself, only to the recorded data.

Answer (score -1):

The magnification is constant because the objective and tube lens are telencentric.